# Are there any inbuilt GUI modules in python 3.4?

Tags: python-3.x, python-module

I am learning python from a video tutorial series that uses a GUI called 'simpleGUI'. 
It is not inbuilt in python so I had to download  install a similar module called 'simpleGUITK'.

I'm new to python and I wish to know if there is any inbuilt module that I can import without any installation  (like I important math or random) which is same as (or at least similar to) simpleguitk?

Because I might need to send some py files to a friend who might not be having the simpleguitk module.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is no GUI module in the standard library. However, some, like Tkinter, are included with most Python distributions.

I strongly advise that you have a look at the [GUI FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3.4/faq/gui.html) in the official documentation.

Comment: The tkinter package is is definitely in the stdlib, as defined by the core developers.  The code is part of the repository, the doc is part of the Library reference, and the tests are part of the test suite.  The tcl/tk dependency is not part of the stdlib, though usually available.  There are a few other stdlib module with similar dependencies.

Comment: OK,  thank you. In addition to the question, suppose I have import a module that I installed and I send the py file to someone who has not installed that module. Will the program run in that system?

Answer (score 0):

A standard build of python includes tkinter. From the [GUI FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3.4/faq/gui.html#tkinter):

> Standard builds of Python include an object-oriented interface to the
>   Tcl/Tk widget set, called tkinter. This is probably the easiest to
>   install (since it comes included with most binary distributions of
>   Python) and use. For more info about Tk, including pointers to the
>   source, see the Tcl/Tk home page. Tcl/Tk is fully portable to the Mac
>   OS X, Windows, and Unix platforms.